Create 251610 matrices as quickly as possible
There are 251610 6 by 6 binary matrices that are inequivalent. We say two matrices are equivalent if there is some permutation of their rows and/or columns that makes them equal.
For example:
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

and
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]

are equivalent but
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

is not equivalent even though it has the same number of ones.
Task
Your code should output all 251610 inequivalent 6 by 6 matrices. You can choose which member of each equivalence class you output but you must only output one from each.
Scoring
I will time your code on my computer as long as it takes less than 60 minutes.
The timing machine
I will run your code in Ubuntu on a AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with 16GB of RAM.
Results

0.31 seconds by Anders Kaseorg in Rust (nightly build)
0.45 seconds by jdt in C++ (ported from Kaseorg)
18.57 seconds by Aspen in Python (ported from Kaseorg)


Related OEIS sequences: A246106, A058004.

Why the downvote?

I didn’t downvote, but I note we have an emergent consensus that “fastest time for one fixed input” is a poor way to score [tag:fastest-code] (because (a) solutions might run much more quickly than you expect and become statistically impossible to distinguish, and (b) there’s no reasonable place to draw a line in the gradient between a solution hyperoptimized for one input and a solution that’s just print(precomputed_answer)). “Largest input within a fixed time” is better.

@AndersKaseorg don't we have a rule that code has to actually compute the output?

Maybe, but if you incentivize moving further in the direction of precomputation, then solvers will move in that direction until the extent to which the rule was broken becomes unclear. For example, they might precompute one of several steps, or they might do an offline search that justifies skipping certain runtime branches for the one input, or their compiler might be smart enough to accidentally optimize away most or all of their program with constant folding. It’s always better to write good incentives.

Rust, 0.27 s unofficial time
Compile with cargo build --release, run with target/release/matrices.
Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "matrices"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
fxhash = "0.2.1"

[profile.release]
lto = true

src/main.rs
use fxhash::FxHashSet;
use std::io::{BufWriter, StdoutLock, Write};

const ROWS: usize = 6;
const COLS: usize = 6;

fn transpose<const A: usize, const B: usize>(m: &[[bool; B]; A]) -> [[bool; A]; B] {
    let mut mt = [[false; A]; B];
    for j in 0..B {
        for i in 0..A {
            mt[j][i] = m[i][j];
        }
    }
    mt
}

fn found_permutations(
    m: &mut [[bool; COLS]; ROWS],
    row_sums: &[u32; ROWS],
    i: u32,
    permuted: bool,
    found: &mut FxHashSet<[[bool; COLS]; ROWS]>,
) {
    if i == ROWS as u32 {
        if permuted {
            let mut mt = transpose(m);
            mt.sort();
            let mtt = transpose(&mt);
            if mtt.is_sorted_by_key(|row| (row.iter().map(|&cell| cell as u32).sum::<u32>(), row)) {
                found.insert(mtt);
            }
        }
    } else {
        found_permutations(m, row_sums, i + 1, permuted, found);
        for i1 in i as usize + 1..ROWS {
            if row_sums[i1] != row_sums[i as usize] {
                break;
            }
            if &m[i1] != &m[i as usize] {
                m.swap(i as usize, i1);
                found_permutations(m, row_sums, i + 1, true, found);
                m.swap(i as usize, i1);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn search(
    m: &mut [[bool; COLS]; ROWS],
    mut i: u32,
    mut j: u32,
    mut row_sum: u32,
    mut min_row_sum: u32,
    mut equal_row: bool,
    equal_cols: &mut [bool; COLS],
    found: &mut FxHashSet<[[bool; COLS]; ROWS]>,
    stdout: &mut BufWriter<StdoutLock<'static>>,
) {
    if row_sum + COLS as u32 - j < min_row_sum {
        return;
    }
    if j == COLS as u32 {
        i += 1;
        if i == ROWS as u32 {
            if !found.remove(&*m) {
                let mut row_sums = [0; ROWS];
                for (row_sum, row) in row_sums.iter_mut().zip(&*m) {
                    *row_sum = row.iter().map(|&cell| cell as u32).sum::<u32>();
                }
                found_permutations(m, &row_sums, 0, false, found);
                for row in &*m {
                    for &cell in row {
                        stdout.write_all(if cell { b"1" } else { b"0" }).unwrap();
                    }
                    stdout.write_all(b" ").unwrap();
                }
                stdout.write_all(b"\n").unwrap();
            }
            return;
        }
        j = 0;
        min_row_sum = row_sum;
        row_sum = 0;
        equal_row = true;
    }
    let equal_col = equal_cols[j as usize];
    if !equal_col || !m[i as usize][j as usize - 1] {
        m[i as usize][j as usize] = false;
        equal_cols[j as usize] = equal_col && !m[i as usize][j as usize - 1];
        search(
            m,
            i,
            j + 1,
            row_sum,
            min_row_sum + (equal_row && m[i as usize - 1][j as usize]) as u32,
            equal_row && !m[i as usize - 1][j as usize],
            equal_cols,
            found,
            stdout,
        );
    }
    m[i as usize][j as usize] = true;
    equal_cols[j as usize] = equal_col && m[i as usize][j as usize - 1];
    search(
        m,
        i,
        j + 1,
        row_sum + 1,
        min_row_sum,
        equal_row && m[i as usize - 1][j as usize],
        equal_cols,
        found,
        stdout,
    );
    equal_cols[j as usize] = equal_col;
}

fn main() {
    let mut equal_cols = [true; COLS];
    equal_cols[0] = false;
    search(
        &mut [[false; COLS]; ROWS],
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        false,
        &mut equal_cols,
        &mut FxHashSet::default(),
        &mut BufWriter::new(std::io::stdout().lock()),
    );
}


That is amazingly fast. Could you explain the main ideas please. How does it work ?

C++ (gcc), 0.38 seconds unofficial time
C++ port of @Ander Kaseorg's Rust code.
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <iomanip>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>

const int ROWS = 6;
const int COLS = 6;

using Matrix = std::array<std::array<bool, COLS>, ROWS>;
int count = 0;

// Optimized custom hash function for std::unordered_set of matrices
struct MatrixHash {
    size_t operator()(const Matrix& m) const {
        size_t hash = 0;
        for (const auto& row : m) {
            size_t rowHash = 0;
            for (bool cell : row) {
                rowHash = (rowHash << 1) | cell;
            }
            hash ^= rowHash + 0x9e3779b9 + (hash << 6) + (hash >> 2);
        }
        return hash;
    }
};

void found_permutations(Matrix& m, const std::array<uint32_t, ROWS>& row_sums, uint32_t i, bool permuted, std::unordered_set<Matrix, MatrixHash>& found) {
    if (i == ROWS) {
        if (permuted) {
            // transpose
            Matrix mt{};
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j) {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
                    mt[j][i] = m[i][j];
                }
            }

            std::sort(mt.begin(), mt.end());
            // transpose
            Matrix mtt{};
            for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; ++j) {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < COLS; ++i) {
                    mtt[j][i] = mt[i][j];
                }
            }

            if (std::is_sorted(mtt.begin(), mtt.end(), [](const auto& row1, const auto& row2) {
                auto sum1 = std::accumulate(row1.begin(), row1.end(), 0u);
                auto sum2 = std::accumulate(row2.begin(), row2.end(), 0u);
                return std::tie(sum1, row1) < std::tie(sum2, row2);
                })) {
                found.insert(mtt);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        found_permutations(m, row_sums, i + 1, permuted, found);
        for (size_t i1 = i + 1; i1 < ROWS; ++i1) {
            if (row_sums[i1] != row_sums[i]) {
                break;
            }
            if (m[i1] != m[i]) {
                std::swap(m[i], m[i1]);
                found_permutations(m, row_sums, i + 1, true, found);
                std::swap(m[i], m[i1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Search function
void search(Matrix& m, uint32_t i, uint32_t j, uint32_t row_sum, uint32_t min_row_sum, bool equal_row, std::array<bool, COLS>& equal_cols, std::unordered_set<Matrix, MatrixHash>& found, std::string& out) {
    if (row_sum + COLS - j < min_row_sum)
        return;

    if (j == COLS) {
        ++i;
        if (i == ROWS) {
            if (found.find(m) == found.end()) {
                std::array<uint32_t, ROWS> row_sums{};
                for (size_t r = 0; r < ROWS; ++r) {
                    row_sums[r] = std::accumulate(m[r].begin(), m[r].end(), 0u);
                }
                found_permutations(m, row_sums, 0, false, found);
                ++count;

                for (const auto& row : m) {
                    for (bool cell : row) {
                        out += cell ? '1' : '0';
                    }
                    out += ' ';
                }
                out += '\n';
            }
            return;
        }
        j = 0;
        min_row_sum = row_sum;
        row_sum = 0;
        equal_row = true;
    }

    bool equal_col = equal_cols[j];

    if (!equal_col || !m[i][j - 1]) {
        m[i][j] = false;
        equal_cols[j] = equal_col && !m[i][j - 1];
        search(m, i, j + 1, row_sum, min_row_sum + (equal_row && m[i - 1][j]), equal_row && !m[i - 1][j], equal_cols, found, out);
    }

    m[i][j] = true;
    equal_cols[j] = equal_col && m[i][j - 1];
    search(m, i, j + 1, row_sum + 1, min_row_sum, equal_row && m[i - 1][j], equal_cols, found, out);
    equal_cols[j] = equal_col;
}

// Main function
int main() {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::array<bool, COLS> equal_cols{};
    equal_cols.fill(true);
    equal_cols[0] = false;

    Matrix m{};
    std::unordered_set<Matrix, MatrixHash> found;

    std::string out;
    out.reserve(11000000);

    search(m, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, equal_cols, found, out);

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - start;

    std::cout << "Count: " << count << '\n';
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " seconds" << '\n';

    // std::cout << out;
}

Try it online!

Rust, 5.225 seconds unofficial time
Based on @Anders Kaseorg's Rust code, I made minor modification:

add matrices count
add timing
user-defined is_sorted_by_key, so we don't need nightly release of rust


use fxhash::FxHashSet;
use std::io::{BufWriter, StdoutLock, Write};
use std::time::Instant;

const ROWS: usize = 6;
const COLS: usize = 6;

fn is_sorted_by_key(arr: &[[bool; COLS]; ROWS]) -> bool {
    for i in 1..ROWS {
        let prev_sum: u32 = arr[i - 1].iter().map(|&cell| cell as u32).sum();
        let curr_sum: u32 = arr[i].iter().map(|&cell| cell as u32).sum();
        if curr_sum < prev_sum || (curr_sum == prev_sum && arr[i] < arr[i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}

fn transpose<const A: usize, const B: usize>(m: &[[bool; B]; A]) -> [[bool; A]; B] {
    let mut mt = [[false; A]; B];
    for j in 0..B {
        for i in 0..A {
            mt[j][i] = m[i][j];
        }
    }
    mt
}

fn found_permutations(
    m: &mut [[bool; COLS]; ROWS],
    row_sums: &[u32; ROWS],
    i: u32,
    permuted: bool,
    found: &mut FxHashSet<[[bool; COLS]; ROWS]>,
) {
    if i == ROWS as u32 {
        if permuted {
            let mut mt: [[bool; 6]; 6] = transpose(m);
            mt.sort();
            let mtt: [[bool; 6]; 6] = transpose(&mt);

            if is_sorted_by_key(&mtt) {
                found.insert(mtt);
            }
        }
    } else {
        found_permutations(m, row_sums, i + 1, permuted, found);
        for i1 in i as usize + 1..ROWS {
            if row_sums[i1] != row_sums[i as usize] {
                break;
            }
            if &m[i1] != &m[i as usize] {
                m.swap(i as usize, i1);
                found_permutations(m, row_sums, i + 1, true, found);
                m.swap(i as usize, i1);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn search(
    m: &mut [[bool; COLS]; ROWS],
    mut i: u32,
    mut j: u32,
    mut row_sum: u32,
    mut min_row_sum: u32,
    mut equal_row: bool,
    equal_cols: &mut [bool; COLS],
    found: &mut FxHashSet<[[bool; COLS]; ROWS]>,
    stdout: &mut BufWriter<StdoutLock<'static>>,
    cnt: &mut u32,
) {
    if row_sum + COLS as u32 - j < min_row_sum {
        return;
    }
    if j == COLS as u32 {
        i += 1;
        if i == ROWS as u32 {
            if !found.remove(&*m) {
                let mut row_sums = [0; ROWS];
                for (row_sum, row) in row_sums.iter_mut().zip(&*m) {
                    *row_sum = row.iter().map(|&cell| cell as u32).sum::<u32>();
                }
                found_permutations(m, &row_sums, 0, false, found);
                for row in &*m {
                    for &cell in row {
                        stdout.write_all(if cell { b"1" } else { b"0" }).unwrap();
                    }
                    stdout.write_all(b" ").unwrap();
                }
                stdout.write_all(b"\n").unwrap();

                *cnt += 1; // Increment the count here
            }
            return;
        }
        j = 0;
        min_row_sum = row_sum;
        row_sum = 0;
        equal_row = true;
    }
    let equal_col = equal_cols[j as usize];
    if !equal_col || !m[i as usize][j as usize - 1] {
        m[i as usize][j as usize] = false;
        equal_cols[j as usize] = equal_col && !m[i as usize][j as usize - 1];
        search(
            m,
            i,
            j + 1,
            row_sum,
            min_row_sum + (equal_row && m[i as usize - 1][j as usize]) as u32,
            equal_row && !m[i as usize - 1][j as usize],
            equal_cols,
            found,
            stdout,
            cnt,
        );
    }
    m[i as usize][j as usize] = true;
    equal_cols[j as usize] = equal_col && m[i as usize][j as usize - 1];
    search(
        m,
        i,
        j + 1,
        row_sum + 1,
        min_row_sum,
        equal_row && m[i as usize - 1][j as usize],
        equal_cols,
        found,
        stdout,
        cnt,
    );
    equal_cols[j as usize] = equal_col;
}

fn main() {
    let mut equal_cols = [true; COLS];
    equal_cols[0] = false;
    let mut cnt = 0;

    let start = Instant::now();

    search(
        &mut [[false; COLS]; ROWS],
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        false,
        &mut equal_cols,
        &mut FxHashSet::default(),
        &mut BufWriter::new(std::io::stdout().lock()),
        &mut cnt,
    );

    let duration = start.elapsed();

    println!("Total count: {}", cnt);
    println!("Execution time: {:?}", duration);
}


Could you explain how it works for us non rustaceans please

What makes your code more than 10 times slower than Kaseorg's?

Python 3.12, 10.33 s unofficial time
Python port of @Ander Kaseorg's Rust code.

import sys
import time

ROWS = 6
COLS = 6

def is_sorted_by_key(arr):
    for i in range(1, ROWS):
        prev_sum = sum(arr[i - 1])
        curr_sum = sum(arr[i])
        if curr_sum < prev_sum or (curr_sum == prev_sum and arr[i] < arr[i - 1]):
            return False
    return True

def transpose(m):
    return [list(row) for row in zip(*m)]

def found_permutations(m, row_sums, i, permuted, found):
    if i == ROWS:
        if permuted:
            mt = transpose(m)
            mt.sort()
            mtt = transpose(mt)
            if is_sorted_by_key(mtt):
                mtt_tuple = tuple(tuple(row) for row in mtt)
                found.add(mtt_tuple)
    else:
        found_permutations(m, row_sums, i + 1, permuted, found)
        for i1 in range(i + 1, ROWS):
            if row_sums[i1] != row_sums[i]:
                break
            if m[i1] != m[i]:
                m[i], m[i1] = m[i1], m[i]
                found_permutations(m, row_sums, i + 1, True, found)
                m[i], m[i1] = m[i1], m[i]

def search(m, i, j, row_sum, min_row_sum, equal_row, equal_cols, found, stdout, cnt):
    if row_sum + (COLS - j) < min_row_sum:
        return
    if j == COLS:
        i += 1
        if i == ROWS:
            m_tuple = tuple(tuple(row) for row in m)
            if m_tuple not in found:
                row_sums = [sum(row) for row in m]
                found_permutations(m, row_sums, 0, False, found)
                for row in m:
                    stdout.write(''.join('1' if cell else '0' for cell in row) + ' ')
                stdout.write('\n')
                cnt[0] += 1
            return
        else:
            j = 0
            min_row_sum = row_sum
            row_sum = 0
            equal_row = True

    if i == 0 and j == 0:
        m[i][j] = False
        equal_cols_prev_j = equal_cols[j]
        equal_cols[j] = False
        search(m, i, j + 1, row_sum, min_row_sum, False, equal_cols, found, stdout, cnt)
        equal_cols[j] = equal_cols_prev_j

        m[i][j] = True
        equal_cols_prev_j = equal_cols[j]
        equal_cols[j] = False
        search(m, i, j + 1, row_sum + 1, min_row_sum, False, equal_cols, found, stdout, cnt)
        equal_cols[j] = equal_cols_prev_j

    elif i == 0:
        equal_col = equal_cols[j]
        if not equal_col or not m[i][j - 1]:
            m[i][j] = False
            prev_equal_cols_j = equal_cols[j]
            equal_cols[j] = equal_col and not m[i][j - 1]
            search(m, i, j + 1, row_sum, min_row_sum, False, equal_cols, found, stdout, cnt)
            equal_cols[j] = prev_equal_cols_j

        m[i][j] = True
        prev_equal_cols_j = equal_cols[j]
        equal_cols[j] = equal_col and m[i][j - 1]
        search(m, i, j + 1, row_sum + 1, min_row_sum, False, equal_cols, found, stdout, cnt)
        equal_cols[j] = prev_equal_cols_j

    elif j == 0:
        m[i][j] = False
        prev_equal_cols_j = equal_cols[j]
        equal_cols[j] = False
        m_i1_j = m[i - 1][j]
        search(m, i, j + 1, row_sum, min_row_sum + int(equal_row and m_i1_j), equal_row and not m_i1_j, equal_cols, found, stdout, cnt)
        equal_cols[j] = prev_equal_cols_j

        m[i][j] = True
        prev_equal_cols_j = equal_cols[j]
        equal_cols[j] = False
        m_i1_j = m[i - 1][j]
        search(m, i, j + 1, row_sum + 1, min_row_sum, equal_row and m_i1_j, equal_cols, found, stdout, cnt)
        equal_cols[j] = prev_equal_cols_j

    else:
        equal_col = equal_cols[j]
        m_i1_j = m[i - 1][j]
        if not equal_col or not m[i][j - 1]:
            m[i][j] = False
            prev_equal_cols_j = equal_cols[j]
            equal_cols[j] = equal_col and not m[i][j - 1]
            search(m, i, j + 1, row_sum, min_row_sum + int(equal_row and m_i1_j), equal_row and not m_i1_j, equal_cols, found, stdout, cnt)
            equal_cols[j] = prev_equal_cols_j

        m[i][j] = True
        prev_equal_cols_j = equal_cols[j]
        equal_cols[j] = equal_col and m[i][j - 1]
        search(m, i, j + 1, row_sum + 1, min_row_sum, equal_row and m_i1_j, equal_cols, found, stdout, cnt)
        equal_cols[j] = prev_equal_cols_j

def main():
    equal_cols = [True] * COLS
    equal_cols[0] = False
    cnt = [0]
    m = [[False] * COLS for _ in range(ROWS)]
    found = set()
    start = time.time()
    stdout = sys.stdout
    search(m, 0, 0, 0, 0, False, equal_cols, found, stdout, cnt)
    duration = time.time() - start
    print(f"Total count: {cnt[0]}")
    print(f"Execution time: {duration} seconds")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


